# In >= Windows 8, how might I return all MSMQ Journal entries for named Queue in powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-8, msmq

As introduced in [MSMQ Cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh405007(v=vs.85).aspx), we now have the ability to query our queue. If I run

```
PS C:\Get-MsmqQueue
```

Then I get a full list of all queue objects on the system. Good.

If I run

```
PS C:\Get-MsmqQueue -QueueType Private
```

Then I get a full list of all Private queue objects on the system. Cool.

However...If I run

```
PS C:\Get-MsmqQueue -Name private$\mt_queuename_request_001
```

I don't get anything back...even though I am using a valid name...so, in turn, running

```
PS C:\Get-MsmqQueue -Name private$\mt_queuename_request_001 -Journal
```

Also gets me nothing...which I'd really like to be able to get this list of Journal entries.

Advice? Success stories?

Comment: `Get-MsmqQueue -Name 'private$\mt_queuename_request_001'` maybe? Wonder if the `$` needed to be escaped. Would have though it would be fine with the slash following it but it is a string so quoting would help. Single quotes prevent variable expansion.

Comment: actually, I removed 'private$\' entirely and I did get an object to return...then using -Journal magically gave me an object...but not the list of objects I was hoping for...our hope to have a little transparency via scripts to MSMQ is becoming nothing more than a smoky veil

Comment: Perhaps then you should be using the `-QueueType` as well? `-QueueType Private` maybe

Comment: [ Get-MsmqQueue -Name 'mt_pdiworkforceqp_request_001' -Journal ] ==  [ Get-MsmqQueue -Name 'mt_pdiworkforceqp_request_001' -QueueType Private  -Journal ]